# Linked list with different elements , possible?

Tags: c++

Hya,

Lemme explain my point.

```
template<typename T>
class node{
  T data;
  template<typename X>
  node<X>* right; // can point to any node<typename> i know its wrong
}
```

so that i can do something like:

```
node<int> a;
a.data = 23;
node<float> b;
b.data =43.6;
a.right= b;
std::cout<< a.data <<a.right->data;
```

**Another example:**

```
template <class Type>
struct vnode {
  Type data;
  vnode<Type> * vnodenext;
  // vrow what_to_put_here // **i don't want to use void ptrs neither want to cast back manually**
}
```

And in main function if I define `vnode` struct of type `string` and another `vnode` of type `int`, then what pointer def should I replace with `vrow` in `vnode` struct definition so that it can point to `vnode` of type `int` or other type of `vnode`? e.g.

```
vnode<string> mystring;
vnode<int> myint;

myint.vrow = &mystring
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't really possible to do what you want because when using templates *you have to know the types involved at compile time*. In contrast, walking a previously constructed linked list requires you to *discover the types in the list at runtime*.

To illustrate, consider this:

```
struct node_base {
    virtual ~node_base() {}
}

template<typename T>
struct node : public node_base {
    T data;
    node_base* right;
}
```

Now you can certainly have a list of `node_base*`, and those nodes can contain any type of data that you want. Constructing the list is not a problem, since at the point you add nodes the static type of `data` is known and you can create a `node<TData>`.

Now the problem is how to get the data back. Assume that there's a function that returns the data inside a node, given a pointer to that node. What should be the functions return type? Clearly (unless you know from beforehand that all data types share a common base) there is no single type that can be returned. That leaves you with:

1. Returning a `void*`
2. Writing a templated function that receives the data type as an argument

However, #2 is not feasible in practice (although it works in theory). You cannot write the data type as a template argument because that would require you to know it at compile time, which defeats the purpose of a multi-data-type list.

Therefore, the only solution left is returning a pointer type (either a `node_base*` or a `void*` to the data itself) and then casting that pointer to a useful type using some mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it's not possible in C++ without some kind of run-time support. But you can use variant type for the values of nodes, see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/variant.html for example.

Answer (score 2):

You should derive your `vnode` template from a common ancestor, i.e.

```
struct vnode_base {
    virtual ~vnode_base() {}
};

template <class Type> 
struct vnode : vnode_base {
   // ...
};
```

and use the `vnode_base*` type for the next-element pointers in your nodes. Since conversion rom base class to ancestors is implicit, the following assignment would be fine: `a.right= &b;`.

To check if a node has a particular type, use C++'s RTTI. There's not really a way to avoid this - you need some kind of runtime type checking.

```
vnode<float>* pf = dynamic_cast<vnode<float>* >(a.right);
if (pf) {
    // here we go
}
```

Comment: The thing is that i will have cast back elements to right , can you help me with auto cast back mechanism?